# Using PdfLatex in OS X?

Tags: macos, pdf, console, latex

This thread [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1512821?start=0&tstart=0) mentions MacTex but it is 2 GB in size and I am trying to find something as small as Apple's `open` command for modularized preview. How can I get something like pdflatex in OS X? Something like open-style modularized `create` for OS X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [BasicTeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html) which includes pdflatex and all the usual tools, but is only 64M.

For a description of what it contains, see [BasicTeX.pdf](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/BasicTeX.pdf).